# Paypal, Guest Checkout not working with .net sdk

Tags: paypal

I wanted to use the PayPal's hosted checkout pages, in my payment processing to avoid PCI compliance. Hosted checkout pages works fine. It gives me response on my website. This process is works good when i use it with pay with paypal account option. But i wanted to work this with guest checkout. User should not be ask to login in PayPal. I have set the option as account not require in paypal. 
It goes to guest checkout page but paypal giving me error as badrequest on payments page.

Is there any other option that it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the flow consistently you need to use the Express Checkout APIs. In your SetExpressCheckout request you'll include the following parameters:

```
SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole
LANDINGPAGE=Billing
USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard
```

You also need to make sure that "PayPal Account Optional" is enabled in your PayPal profile. It's under Payment Receiving Preferences, or Website Payment Preferences, or something like that.

After all above changes, clear your browser's cache - cookies and try to check again, It will give guest checkout option.

Comment: Thanks Niraj great help